# Add more dropdown with dynamic values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have three dropdown(two dropdown with dynamic values and one empty dropdown) and one button. When I click the button, The same four things(two dropdown with dynamic values, one empty dropdown and one button) will be append to my code.

Now I want to fill the third dropdown with dynamic values on changing the the first dropdown.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-12" >
  <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-right:0px;">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">  <p>Class</p></label>
      <select   class="form-control select2" name="class_select[]" data-target="#">
        <?php
        foreach($conn->query('SELECT * FROM school_class') as $row) 
        {
          echo'<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>'; 
        }?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-right:0px;"> 
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">  <p>Section </p></label>
      <select   class="form-control select2" name="section_select[]" data-target="#">
        <?php
        foreach($conn->query('SELECT * FROM school_section') as $row) 
        {
          echo'<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>'; 
        }?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-right:0px;">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">  <p>Subject</p></label>
      <select   class="form-control select2" name="subject_select[]" data-target="#">
        <option>Please Select</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-top:45px;">
    <span><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add btn green" >Add More</a></span>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="contents"></div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".add").click(function() {
          $('<div class="col-md-12 "><div class="col-md-3" style="padding-right:0px;"><div class="form-group"><select   class="form-control select2" name="class_select[]" data-target="#"><?php foreach($conn->query('SELECT * FROM school_class') as $row){ echo'<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>'; }?></select></div></div> <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-right:0px;"><div class="form-group"><select   class="form-control select2" name="section_select[]" data-target="#"><?php
          foreach($conn->query('SELECT * FROM school_section') as $row) {
            echo'<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';}?></select></div></div> <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-right:0px;"><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" name="m" ></div></div><span class="rem" ><a class="btn red" style="width:7.3%;margin-left:15px;" href="javascript:void(0);" >Remove</span></div>').appendTo(".contents");
      });
  });
</script>

<script>
$('.contents').on('click', '.rem', function() {
  $(this).parent("div").remove();
});
</script>
```

Comment: *..Now I want to fill the third dropdown with dynamic values on changing the the first dropdown.* **OK**. But, What Problem You Faced?

Comment: I want to know how to list some dynamic values according to the first dropdown value(onchange)

Comment: So, 3rd dropdown will get values from first dropdown. Correct. On every selection.

Comment: Yeah.. Correct.. based on the first dropdown value, third dropdown value will change

Comment: Your "Jquery" code looks frightening. Are you familiar with jQuery at all?

Comment: No I don't have much knowledge in jquery